# 'Went' vs 'have all gone' vs 'goes' after a future perfect clause

Tags: tense-agreement, future-perfect

> 1. He will have waited there until the lights **went** out.
> 2. He will have waited there until the lights **have all gone** out.
> 3. He will have waited there until the lights **goes** out.

Are those sentences possible? Are there any differences  in  meaning?

Comment: Contrary to Ronald Sole's answer below, I'm actually OK with the second one and think that it's the most appropriate to convey just how long the person has been waiting (that even "all the lights have gone out"). That is, in this context, I would choose number two as the statement with the most emphasis on "waiting."

Comment: Meanwhile, number one is wrong and number three is OK as long as you change it to "go" since you have a plural subject, "lights," but again, it wouldn't be my preferred choice.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang -- Your comments would make a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

All those sentences are possible, with the exception of the typo in Sentence #3 in which the verb and noun disagree: "Until the lights **goes** out" should be "Until the lights **go** out." My answer will assume that was the intended wording.

**[FUTURE PERFECT](https://www.ef.com/ca/english-resources/english-grammar/future-perfect/)**

All quotes and references in this part are taken from this future perfect link.

These sentences are using the future perfect tense, which "refers to a completed action in the future."

**The Function of the Future Perfect**:

> When we use this tense we are projecting ourselves forward into the
>   future and looking back at an action that will be completed some time
>   later than now. It is most often used with a time expression.

In all of these sentences, "waiting" is projected into the future to a point in time when the waiting is over. Thus, "He will have waited there" at some point in the future, which future point in time is expressed below.

***Time Expression* in Each of These Sentences**

1. until the lights went out.
2. until the lights have all gone out.
3. until the lights go out.

It is possible that "he will have waited there" until that point in time. So yes, all of these sentences are possible with regards to the question asked at the top of this thread.

**GRAMMATICAL CORRECTNESS**

Are all these sentences grammatically correct? No.

While these sentences may be possible and while people may speak like Sentences 1 and 3 in the vernacular, the only grammatically correct one is Sentence 2:

> He will have waited there until the lights **have** all **gone** out.

I think this is similar to this [future perfect example](https://www.ef.com/ca/english-resources/english-grammar/future-perfect/):

> **I will have been** here for six months on June 23rd.

There are two time points; these are:

1. Utterance or speech, which occurs in the present six months before June 23rd but will be in the past by June 23rd.
2. Time spent here, i.e. June 23rd, which is in the future at the time of the utterance.

In this perspective the sentences in the question are future perfect, i.e. they use "will have been." However, the sentence structure is more complex in that the second part contains verbs, not just a simple time or date. I cannot find an exact sentence structure like this but I did find helpful information at [Future-Perfect-In-Past Tense](https://glossary.sil.org/term/future-perfect-past-tense).

[**Future-Perfect-In-Past Tense**](https://glossary.sil.org/term/future-perfect-past-tense)

From *Future-Perfect-In-Past Tense*:

> The tense refers to a time that is in the future, relative to another
>   point in the past, but is in the past relative to a point in its
>   future.

They provide an example:

> John left for the front; by the time he should return, the field
>   *would have been* burnt to stubble.

That is British English. In American English it would look like this:

> John left for the front; by the time he would return, the field *would
>   have been* burned to  stubble.

**Three Time Points**

A Future-Perfect-In-Past Tense has three time points.

1. The time of speech or utterance, which happens after the events are in the past.
2. John's leaving, which happens before the utterance and before the burning of the field.
3. The burning of the field, which happens after John's leaving but before the utterance.

Those three time points are necessary and must agree for future perfect in past tense.

**Comparing Sentence 2**

Is this example the same as Sentence 2 in the question? The question does not give enough information but I don't think so. The only time I have ever seen this exact sentence structure used was when plans were being made for the future. I'll make up an example, using Sentence 2 from the question:

> We will meet Karl backstage when we finish; he will have waited there
>   until the lights have all gone out.

Time Points:

1. Utterance, which is before Karl's waiting there and before the lights go out.
2. Karl waiting, which is after the utterance, but before the lights go out.
3. Lights go out, which is after the utterance and after the waiting.

The example of Karl:

- is the same as the example of John in that there are three time points.
- differs from the example of John in that the utterance happens before the other two time points.

**Conclusion re Grammatically Correct**

I cannot find an example online for this problem but I trust my own experience with native English-speakers. Based on the above examples in *Future Perfect* and *Future Perfect In Past*, I believe Sentence 2 in the question is grammatically correct.

---

Given the above explanation, it should be clear why I say all three sentences are about an expected future event and that Ronald Sole's answer is wrong. "Have waited" is past tense. Putting "will" in front of "have waited" puts it in the future, i.e. future perfect. I will explain sentence by sentence.

**First Sentence**

The first sentence makes sense and is possible in the following scenario.

> *He will have waited there until the lights went out.*
>
> A group of people are planning what they will do with their evening
>   after the lights have gone out. One person, whom we'll call him Karl
>   for the sake of discussion, is supposed to wait somewhere until after
>   the lights are out. In the meantime, while he is waiting on the
>   lights, the others will be doing something else (we are not told
>   what). By the time they are done doing that other thing, Karl will
>   have waited there until the lights went out. As they make out the
>   exact schedule, they mark the number of minutes that Karl will have
>   waited there until the lights went out.

Note that this first sentence actually worked well in two different occasions in that little story. It is grammatically correct.

**Second Sentence**

Using the above scenario, I can use it the same way, i.e. as a proposed situation at an expected time point in the future.

> *He will have waited there until the lights have all gone out.*
>
> By the time we have finished what we are doing, Karl will have waited
>   there until the lights have all gone out.

That means the same as the First Sentence and is grammatically correct.

In this case, "have gone" means the same as "went." The word "all" is optional.

**Third Sentence**

As has already been discussed in the comments above, under the Opening Question, this sentence contains an error, i.e. "lights goes out" should say "lights go out." I have edited it for the discussion below thus:

> *He will have waited there until the lights go out.*

Continuing to use the scenario of the friends planning their evening, it is possible to use this sentence the same way as the other two. In the vernacular, "go" is often used instead of the grammatically correct "have gone" or "went." Nobody notices, but "go" is present tense while "have waited" is past tense.

It is possible that he "will have waited until the lights went out" or that he "will have waited until the lights have gone out." "Went" and "have gone" are past tense and agree with the past tense of "have waited" in the first part of the sentence. Adding "will" in front of "have waited" does not change this. "Will have waited" requires in the second part the sentence a corresponding verb that is in the past tense. For this reason, it is not correct to say he "will have waited until the lights go out." "Go" cannot be in the past; it is always in the present or future.

Put another way:

- will have waited = will be in the past *at some future point in time*
- have gone = past tense
- went = past tense
- go = present tense or future tense; it cannot be in the past at some future point in time.

The Second Sentence containing "have gone" is the correct way to say it if one wishes to use a form of the word "go." In other words, the past tense of "go" is "gone."

Comment: I have never seen a past tense with the future perfect construction, either a present or a present perfect tense is accompanied, either of those would make sense but past tense seems weird, do you have any references if you could post? The "go" in the future tense doesn't mean the definition of "present tense". It implies "it has gone".

Comment: I added a major part with links. Is it consistent or does my answer need more work?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood me, I said if your clause has future perfect tense( will+have) then it must be accompanied by present or present perfect tense. The (would+have) is not exactly "future" perfect but showing an aspect of future in the PAST. And in English we use Past Tense for three things;  to explain actual past event, imagining an event in the present and lastly, imagining an event that might take place in the real future. And with time clauses we either use Present or Past tense.

Comment: In the end your alternate way of understanding "have gone" must be understood as an event that is "completed "rather than "past tense". If it were to be the case of just being in the past  then Present Perfect and Past tense would have no distinction at all.

Comment: Okay. So are you basically saying my answer is wrong? If so, I will delete it lest I mislead someone. I've spent many hours on this and I think I'm over my head. I'm fluent in English but do not have enough formal grammar education to actually parse this stuff. Let me know because I'm rather confused, but I can't put in any more time on it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm okay with (2) and (3) but the (1)  is simply wrong ordering of tenses, I mean you'd still be understood by using (1) but from a pure grammatical point of view (1) is definitely incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

Take your statements in two parts.

The first part of each is about the expected behaviour in the past of a person who was waiting until lights went out. At the time of speaking, the lights have gone out and the person is presumably no longer waiting.

So the first statement is correct:

> > He will (or would) have waited there until the lights went out.

The second statement confuses tenses. Using the present perfect indicates that the lights have not yet all gone out. The action is not completed. But the sense of the statement is that the lights have indeed gone out. So it's wrong.

If he is still waiting there and some lights are still on, you would have to say:

> > He will be waiting there until all the lights have all gone out.

The third statement is also wrong. *Lights* is plural and thus would *go out*, not *goes out*. So the way to write this is:

> > He will be waiting there until all the lights go out.

Which means very much the same as *until all the lights have gone out*.

Comment: So what is the difference between          he will have waited until the lights went out  and  he would  have waited until the lights went out. The second one takes place in the past   would have waited and went but the first one takes place in the present   will have waited and went is past simple , is it possible

Comment: @user5577 The two tenses are frequently used interchangeably by English speakers. I would prefer: *He will have waited.....* as a simple statement of assumed fact; but I'd prefer *He would have waited.....* if it were followed by a conditional clause such as: *He would have waited until the lights went out unless he got a taxi.* In both cases he is no longer waiting, the events concerned have already taken place. For more on will/would, see: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/when-should-i-use-would-would-have-will-and-will-have

Comment: What do you think about teacher KSHUANG's answer, he said that both sentences He will have waited there until the lights have all gone out.and He will have waited there until the lights go out. are possible

Comment: @user5577 I respectfully disagree. If *He will have waited there...* he is no longer waiting there so I don't think that one can talk about *how long he HAS been waiting* as it implies that he is still waiting. For me, it's a case of how long he HAD been waiting.

Answer (score -1):

The second example is correct. The first and third are possible, but not correct. They are jarring to read.

Comment: Generally we like answers to have a little more detail than this; add a *why* to your response.